# Gmail/Google calendar: cancel event by emailed ICS file

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar

I am emailing ICS files to my users to help manage appointments automatically,   when either party clicks a cancellation link on my website,  I'm sending a new email with a cancellation ICS file.

my target market primarily uses gmail.

when they receive the initial email, they can click to add the event from the ics file to their google calendar.

when they receive a cancellation email, there is no way to update the event.

if it's relevant,  the email comes from support@domain.com

is there any way to do this with ICS files via email?

---

Original event ICS:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//sebbo.net//ical-generator//EN
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:AUniqueIDThatMatches
SEQUENCE:0
DTSTAMP:20181004T184001Z
DTSTART:20181005T210000Z
DTEND:20181005T213000Z
SUMMARY:SESSION
LOCATION:Online session
DESCRIPTION:SESSION
ORGANIZER;CN="Admin":mailto:support@domain.com
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;CN="Admin":MAILTO:support@domain.com
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;CN="ben hart":MAILTO:attendee@domain.com
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
TRIGGER:-PT10M
DESCRIPTION:SESSION
END:VALARM
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:AUDIO
TRIGGER:-PT5M
ATTACH;VALUE=URI:Basso
END:VALARM
STATUS:CONFIRMED
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

cancellation ICS:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//sebbo.net//ical-generator//EN
METHOD:CANCEL
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:AUniqueIDThatMatches
SEQUENCE:1
DTSTAMP:20181004T184057Z
DTSTART:20181005T210000Z
DTEND:20181005T213000Z
SUMMARY:SESSION
LOCATION:Online session
DESCRIPTION:SESSION
ORGANIZER;CN="Admin":mailto:support@domain.com
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;CN="Admin":MAILTO:support@domain.com
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;CN="ben hart":MAILTO:attendee@domain.com
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
TRIGGER:-PT10M
DESCRIPTION:SSESSION
END:VALARM
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:AUDIO
TRIGGER:-PT5M
ATTACH;VALUE=URI:Basso
END:VALARM
STATUS:CANCELLED
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: 1) code used? literally the ics files I'm sending are shown (anonymized) 2) problem encountered? when they receive a cancellation email, there is no way to update the event.  -  So I'm not sure what else you'd like me to add...

Answer (score 1):

First, if this is an invitation, you should have

```
METHOD:REQUEST
```

instead of METHOD:PUBLISH in the original invite. This is important as a CANCEL is valid, in theory at least, only following a REQUEST.

Then, you should remove the VALARM junk from both messages. They will be ignored in the request anyway.

Finally, do you include the correct METHOD in the content-type of the cancellation email ?

Comment: Cancel event is working fine with METHOD:PUBLISH in outlook but not working with gmail. Is there any way so that cancel event should work in gmail with METHOD:PUBLISH

Comment: Out of all possible explanations / combinations of suggested key/value pairs this is the only solution that works for google calendar, ical and all other services that I've tried.